# Handling runtime.DeadlineExceededError in Django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Running Django 1.2 running on App Engine:

Django calls the `process_exception` function on all Middleware classes when handling an `Exception` raised by a view function. However, `google.appengine.runtime.DeadlineExceededError`, the class used when any view takes more than 60 seconds to execute, extends from `BaseException`, not `Exception`, so `process_exception` is never called by Django.

Is there an alternative solution for handling `runtime.DeadlineExceededError` exceptions across all views?

(This [Google App Engine Issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2110) could be a related).